# How to reference a model value from within nested controller in angular-formly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I'm using angular-formly and am trying to do cascading select options inside of repeating sections and am running into problems with nested scopes when trying to load select options asynchronously.

In the nested cascading-select controllers, if I inject `$scope`, they no longer have access to the main form's `$scope.model`, causing the watchers to not work. If I don't inject `$scope`, the watchers work, but `$scope.to.loading/$scope.to.options` are undefined, so I can't set the cascaded selection options.

How can I access `$scope.model` in my nested controllers, preserving both their ability to watch `$scope.model` attributes and to insert options in fields on their level? I've looked into using `$scope.$parent`, but the number of parents I need to append to `$scope` gets ridiculous fast depending on the level of repeating sections, and I'd rather avoid hard-coding that.

I have a [somewhat-simplified, working example](http://jsbin.com/fuxohovohe/edit?html,js,output) of what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'm using a watcher to set a `$rootScope` attribute, which both the nested controllers and main form controller can access. The first field is where the user selects a sport, and then the nested repeating sections have fields whose options are populated based on the first field (sport) using a factory.

I'd like a better solution than this temporary workaround, if possible, to avoid using `$rootScope`. I'm pretty new to angularJS, so I'm sorry if I didn't do a great job explaining the issue, and I'm sure a lot of my code is pretty cringe-worthy, but any help specific to the question would be very appreciated!

Mitch

Comment: You're right to avoid using `$rootScope`. I would recommend sharing data via a `service` (https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services)

Comment: @kentcdodds Thank you. I spent quite a bit of time when I first encountered the issue making a service that would accomplish it, but I found rootScope to be the easier solution. From what I understand, it doesn't sound like I'll be able to reduce the number of watchers with a service, either, since I'll need to watch for changes in the parent field, update the service, and watch for changes in the service from the nested field controllers. I hoped that formly might have something integrated to  reference parent fields, but I'll see if I can come up with a good solution with a service. :)